# How to Release Electron app for Windows or Mac or Linux system?

Tags: windows, macos, angular, desktop-application, electron-builder

I have created an App With Angular 2 and I have created ios and apk file after some modification with ionic

I wanted to create desktop app file with same project

I have gone through many resources for electron but I could not get any clear idea about

how I can create an exe  file from electron app file  for Windows or Mac app file or Linux executable file
If any one know any clear references about how I can Create an Executable file for windows or Mac or Linux by Electorn Please answer bellow

This will be very helpful for me to learn Electron

Answer (score 2):

App distribution example using Electron-quick-start project from official [electron.atom.io](https://electron.atom.io/) page:

---

```
# Clone the Quick Start repository
$ git clone https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start

# Go into the repository
$ cd electron-quick-start

# Install the dependencies and run
$ npm install && npm start
```

---

For application distribution we will use Electron-builder: A complete solution to package and build a ready for distribution Electron app for macOS, Windows and Linux with “auto update” support out of the box.*

From "Quick Setup Guide" section at [electron-builder docs](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder#user-content-quick-setup-guide):

1. Specify the standard fields in the application `package.json` — `name`, `description`, `version` and `author`.
2. Specify the build configuration in the `package.json` as follows:

   "build": {
   "appId": "your.id",
   "mac": {
   "category": "your.app.category.type"
   }
   }
3. Add `electron-builder` at `package.json` (missing step from docs!):

   "devDependencies": {
   "electron": "1.6.6"**,
   "electron-builder": "17.1.2"**   }
4. Create a directory build in the root of the project and save a `background.png` (macOS DMG background), `icon.icns` (macOS app icon) and `icon.ico` (Windows app icon) into it.

   The Linux icon set will be generated automatically based on the macOS `icns` file.
5. Add the scripts key to the development `package.json`:

   "scripts": {
     "pack": "build --dir",
     "dist": "build"
   }

Then you can run `npm run dist` in your root app folder (to package in a distributable format (e.g. dmg, windows installer, deb package)).
When finished, you can see that there is an appropriate installer at `app/dist` folder!

Comment: This only builds for Mac, not for Windows or Linux.

Comment: for windows use electron-builder

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [electron-builder](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder#quick-setup-guide)?

Comment: I have gone through both documentation of electron-builder and electron package manager but could understand clearly so If there are any clear full documentation of doing that  can you please provide